# MultiIndex DataFrame - Getting only the possible values of a lower level index given an upper level index value

Tags: python, pandas

When I slice into a `MultiIndex` `DataFrame` by a level 0 index value, I want to know the possible level 1+ index values that fall under that initial value. If my wording doesn't make sense, here's an example:

```
>>> arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
... ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'],
... ['a','b','a','b','b','b','b','b']]
>>> tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
>>> index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second','third'])
>>> s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(8), index=index)
>>> s
first  second  third
bar    one     a       -0.598684
       two     b        0.351421
baz    one     a       -0.618285
       two     b       -1.175418
foo    one     b       -0.093806
       two     b        1.092197
qux    one     b       -1.515515
       two     b        0.741408
dtype: float64
```

`s`'s `index` looks like:

```
>>> s.index
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'bar', u'baz', u'foo', u'qux'], [u'one', u'two'], [u'a', u'b']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],
           names=[u'first', u'second', u'third'])
```

When I take just the section of `s` whose `first` index value is `foo`, and look up the index of that I get:

```
>>> s_foo = s.loc['foo']
>>> s_foo
second  third
one     b       -0.093806
two     b        1.092197
dtype: float64

>>> s_foo.index
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'one', u'two'], [u'a', u'b']],
           labels=[[0, 1], [1, 1]],
           names=[u'second', u'third'])
```

I want the `index` of `s_foo` to act as if the higher level of `s` does not exist, yet we can see in `s_foo.index`'s `levels` attribute that `a` is still considered a potential value of index `third`, despite the fact that `s_foo` only has `b` as a possible value.

Essentially, what I want to find are all the possible `third` values of `foo_s`, i.e. `b` and only `b`. Right now I do `set(s_foo.reset_index()['third'])`, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create s_foo and explicitly drop the unused levels:

```
s_foo = s.loc['foo']
s_foo.index = s_foo.index.remove_unused_levels()
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Reset index seems like the right way to go, seems like you don't want it to be an index (the result you're getting is the way indexes work).

```
s.reset_index(level=2).groupby(level=[0])['third'].unique()
```

or if you want counts

```
s.reset_index(level=2).groupby(level=[0])['third'].value_counts()
```